Looking for opinion on basement insulation
Looking for opinions on the best way to insulate my basement walls as I plan to add a finished area to the basement. The previous owner put spray foam along the top as pictured. I'm thinking of putting insulation boards along the flat concrete part below and then adding more spray foam in between the boards and the spray foam to fill in the gaps... Am I thinking about this the right way or completely off base? The tempturature in the basement is pretty much the same as the upstairs.
IMG-3584.jpg
IMG-3585.jpg
IMG-3586.jpg

As an opinion, you are wasting a lot of good space. Create a knee wall where your current studs are positioned, anchor a 2 x 4 stud to the outer vertical wall and connect the two walls with a 2 x 4 joist hanger on the outer vertical and fastened to the vertical on the knee wall. Create the wall on the outside vertical wall anchoring to the horizontals and the underside of the floor joists. Insulate the walls and apply a vapor barrier on the interior. You now have additional storage space potential were applicable. Put in some pot lights in the space for atmosphere. .

Thanks, Yes I do plan to build in the shelving there (the existing framing was put in by previous owner). Do you think foam boards would be the best for the insulation? Figure I can attach them to the flat part of the wall easy enough but for the framing that covers the rounded part would I just attached the boards to the back side of the framing?

Fiberglass is your better choice in this situation. Too much cutting, fitting and gluing with foam given the wall variation.
